# Querying a non-normalized table

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table with many to many relationships, I need to omit 3 types of properties (starting with 0, starting with 1 and having a - in the property) and only select the users which have only 1 type of property which is an alphanumeric string.

Please advise how can it be achieved in SQL.

```
User        Property
------      ----------
A1          0XXX
A1          1XXX
A1          X-XXX
A1          ABC2

A2          0XXX
A2          AC2B
A2          X-XXX

A3          0XXX
A3          1XXX

A4          DEF0
```

Comment: like `WHERE LEFT(Property, 1) <> 0 AND LEFT(Property, 1) <> 1 AND NOT CONTAINS(Property, '-')`?

Comment: consider reviewing [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then come back and update your question; in particular, provide the query(s) you've tried so far, the results of said quey(s), and the desired results (for the sample data you've provided)

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) and version; the different products/versions have different functions which may be of help

Comment: what's the expected output for `('A5','XYZ1') , ('A5', 'ABCD'), ('A5', 'DEFH')` ... you select `A5` or you ignore `A5` (because it has more than '1 type of property which is an alphanumeric string')?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT [User]
FROM tab
EXCEPT
SELECT [User]
FROM tab
WHERE LEFT(Property,1) IN ('0','1')
  OR Property LIKE '%-%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
WHERE user NOT IN 
(
    SELECT user FROM <table>
    WHERE Property LIKE '%-%'
    OR Property LIKE '0%'
    OR Property LIKE '1%'
)
AND Property LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```